# Fixed Background

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to set up my page so the background will not scroll with the page. However, I want to set up a minimum dimensions for the background image, so if a user re sized their window, it would not go lower than my minimum dimensions, and then force a scroll...Is this possible? I have my window set to a minimum of width 1024px, so I want my background to always at least span 1024px wide.

**Also while I'm on the subject of my background. My image is essentially one image duplicated twice but the second image is flipped horizontally. How could I implement it so it is duplicated through css rather than doing it manually and loading a file twice as big?

Here's what I have now. It works with the background not scrolling, but I'm not sure how to set the minimum dimensions on it.

```
body {
    min-width: 1024px;
    min-height: 700px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    max-height: 1080px;

    width: 90%;
    height; 90%;

    background: url(/style/images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    <!-- FOR IE -->
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried allowing the image to be repeated? It also looks like your background is just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/EcyR6/

Comment: height and width may supply 100% of the body?

Comment: Have you looked into the photo flipping property? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/flip-an-image/

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure how to implement it with a repeated background (Eg I want to display an image as half background, and then flip the image to fill the rest of my background)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a few things you could do... The first one would be just taking out the "fixed" property and leaving everything the exact same. That image can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EcyR6/2/).

**Before:**

```
background: url(http://sereedmedia.com/srmwp/wp-content/uploads/kitten.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
```

**After:**

```
background: url(http://sereedmedia.com/srmwp/wp-content/uploads/kitten.jpg) no-repeat center center;
```

Next, you can attempt to put two images next to each other and flip the image to become horizontal but in all reality, you're probably better off just combining and mirroring the two images like you have already done. Here is another [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EcyR6/3/) to find that you can indeed, put two images next to one another.

Now the fun part comes when you need to flip one image and keep the other the same (hence why it would be easier for you to just keep the single image photo). The code for that is below:

```
-moz-transform: scaleX(-1);
-o-transform: scaleX(-1);
 -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  filter: FlipH;
  -ms-filter: "FlipH";
```

However, I can only make the photo flip whenever it is NOT the background image, in this next [link](http://jsfiddle.net/EcyR6/4/), you will find that I made a container for the image using a div tag.

I hope you like kittens.

Comment: this works almost perfectly. I just combined the mirrored images into one file. The only problem I get, is when I change my window size, my background image doesn't fill to the bottom of the page.

And yes I enjoyed the kittens

Comment: You may need to adjust the height accordingly, are you keeping your height to max? Or is the user going beyond your max height you have specified?

Comment: the user is going beyond the max, I was hoping for it to resize if it goes larger (essentially a stretch to fit with minimum dimensions)

Comment: You may be dealing with a more complex answer that would involve jQuery/Javascript due to the front end of the website continuously having to reformat the picture in order to keep up with the user scrolling. In shorter terms, this is possible but to keep it simple I would just use a max height.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to change the "`cover`" on `background-size` if the browser windows minimizes to a certain threshold. Consider using a media query:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) { 
    body { background-size: 1100px; 
    (or whatever)

         }
                                          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-image:url("img_tree.png");

background-repeat:no-repeat;

background-position:right top;

background-attachment:fixed;
```

you can try background image in this manner